# How can i filter with checkbox by these lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new with javascript i don't know how to make filter with checkbox. I tried a lot and spend too much time but i couldn't make it. i request to community please help me to solve this issue.

```
<div id="checkbox_div">
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Apple">
        Apple
    </label>
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Banana">
        Banana
    </label>
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Orange">
        Orange
    </label>
</div>
```

here is checkbox button when someone check Apple and Orange and banana then its show the list where apple and orange both or banana is inside but if he/she uncheck again on one of them ( Apple, Orange, Banana )  then it removes only those where its value is not is the list.

```
<ul class="fruits_lists">
    <li>Apple, PineApple, Apricots, Orange </li>
    <li>Banana, Blueberries, Orange, Apricots </li>
    <li>Apple, Cherries, Cantaloupe, Banana </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: loop over and check text for the value[s]

Comment: how could i use value?

Comment: Do you know how to bind events to elements and read the value of an input?

Comment: actually i am new with javascript and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
[].forEach.call(cbs, function(cb) {
cb.addEventListener("click", function() {
 const listSelected = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[name="list_services"]:checked')].map(ele=>ele.value);
 document.querySelectorAll('.fruits_lists li').forEach(ele=>listSelected.some(l=>ele.textContent.includes(l)) ? (ele.style.display = "block") : (ele.style.display = "none"))

});
});
```

```html
<div id="checkbox_div">
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Apple">
        Apple
    </label>
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Banana">
        Banana
    </label>
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Orange">
        Orange
    </label>
</div>

<ul class="fruits_lists">
    <li>Apple, PineApple, Apricots, Orange </li>
    <li>Banana, Blueberries, Orange, Apricots </li>
    <li>Apple, Cherries, Cantaloupe, Banana </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes bro very close to it. could you please bit more edit, when check apple and banana both its should show both item list, here when we check both apple and banana it removes other list where apple is already there. – abnoor 16 secs ago    Edit

Comment: @abnoor, check now

Comment: yes it is. thank you very much brother Jazzak Allah :-)

Comment: is there any way to also add class to list?

Comment: @abnoor, what do you mean add class to list

Comment: where you write display block and none?

Comment: @abnoor, this a an example with class list 
https://jsfiddle.net/h1x09q5m/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```js
// Cache your elements up front
const checkboxContainer = document.querySelector('#checkbox_div');
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('#checkbox_div input[type="checkbox"]');
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.fruits_lists li');

// Add an event listener to the checkbox container to listen
// to changes
checkboxContainer.addEventListener('change', handleChange, false);

// A function that unchecks all the checkboxes
function reset() {
  checkboxes.forEach(box => box.checked === false);
}

// A function that hides all the items
function hide() {
  items.forEach(item => item.classList.add('hidden'));
}

// A function that `filters` out the checkboxes that
// are selected and then `maps` over those boxes to get
// their values (into an array)
function getCheckedValues(checkboxes) {
  return [...checkboxes]
    .filter(box => box.checked)
    .map(box => box.value);
}

// The function that is called when a change is made to
// any checkbox
function handleChange(e) {

  // We get the array of values of only the checked boxes
  const values = getCheckedValues(checkboxes);

  // If the array is empty hide everything
  if (!values.length) {
    hide();
  } else {

    // Otherwise iterate through the items
    items.forEach(item => {

      // Grab the textContent from each item
      const { textContent } = item;

      // If all of the values are included in the textContent return true,
      // otherwise false
      const containsValue = values.some(value => textContent.includes(value));

      // If containsValue is true set the item's display to 'block',
      containsValue && item.classList.remove('hidden');
    });
  }
}

reset();
hide();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="checkbox_div">
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Apple">
        Apple
    </label>
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Banana">
        Banana
    </label>
    <label> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="list_services" value="Orange">
        Orange
    </label>
</div>

<ul class="fruits_lists">
    <li>Apple, PineApple, Apricots, Orange </li>
    <li>Banana, Blueberries, Orange, Apricots </li>
    <li>Apple, Cherries, Cantaloupe, Banana </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you man it is very close to it. could you please bit more edit, when check apple and banana both its should show both item list, here when we check both apple and banana it removes other list where apple is already there.

Comment: Try replacing `values.every` with `values.some` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @abnoor, I updated mine with with `some` and it now adds/removes a class instead.

Comment: now if we uncheck apple and the row where only apple is there still showing